# How do I save podcasts to the new Apple podcasts app?

Tags: podcasts, ios, podcasts.app

This seems like one of those dumb questions, where the answer is, "that happens automatically, silly!"

But as far as I can tell, while my podcast subscription shows the last 10 or so episodes, they don't seem to be saved on the device.

I came to this conclusion when one stopped playing as soon as the buffer ran out after losing signal, and the others all became unplayable (greyed out).

Is there some way to save episodes on-device int he Apple app?

If not, is there an app that can (which also handles subscriptions and works with the device-wide audio UI, so headphone controls work, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The podcast app is a bit convoluted to know which episodes are unplayed but available for streaming and unplayed and downloaded. I haven't been able to tell visually which is which and am in the habit of turning on AirPlane mode to check which podcasts are actually downloaded then going back and downloading them if needed before leaving Wi-Fi or wireless range.

[The manual](http://help.apple.com/iphone) for iOS 6 is actually great for things like this.  (If hit that link your phone, you can save it as a webapp on your home screen for other issues.)

Here's the relevant section on your question:

> • Download an episode so you can listen to it when you’re not connected to Wi-Fi: Tap the "down-arrow" icon next to
>   any episode.

[image: podcast download still image]

Comment: Nice addition - wish I could upvote again...